# Running kotlintest in maven

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlintest

I've been struggling for a while now trying to get kotlintest tests to run properly from maven.  I'm far from a maven expert so I'm hoping someone can tell me where I'm going wrong.

I started with the maven example from the kotlin repo [here](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/tree/master/kotlintest-samples/kotlintest-samples-maven), and that works fine.  The issue arises when more tests are added.  When I add more tests (in nested packages), only a single test actually gets "run", the others just seem to have a dummy test method run.  For example, given the following hierarchy:

[image: project structure]

With [this](https://pastebin.com/9df5P0XA) pom.xml, running `mvn test` gives:

```
Running BarTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec <<< FAILURE! - in BarTest
should fail  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: true but was: false
Running test.BarTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec - in test.BarTest
Running a.AThingTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec - in a.AThingTest
Running newtest.FooTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in newtest.FooTest

Results :

Failed tests:
  BarTest expected: true but was: false

Tests run: 5, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The very first one: `Running BarTest` is actually the right test (and has an intentional failure).  All the other ones (`Running test.BarTest`, `Running a.AThingTest`, `Running newtest.FooTest`) aren't actually running my tests (I have intentional failures there too), and appear to be just some dummy tests (perhaps from the dummy `@Test` in `IntelliTestMarker`?).  I included a sample of one of those test files below.

What do I need to do to run all of my actual tests? And, preferably, not have the 'dummy' tests show up in the output?

BarTest.kt:

```
package test

import io.kotlintest.shouldBe
import io.kotlintest.specs.ShouldSpec

class BarTest : ShouldSpec() {
    init {
        "Bar" {
            should("succeed") {
                true shouldBe true
            }
            should("fail") {
                false shouldBe true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is embarrassingly quite simple. Upgrade to 3.0.3. This was a bug in 3.0.0 to 3.0.2 that affected Maven builds.

For the sake of completeness here are the full maven project instructions for KotlinTest 3.0.x

Add this dependency to your `<dependencies>` section.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kotlintest</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlintest-runner-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure you add the `surefire` plugin to your `<build><plugins>` section and with it add the jUnit platform surefire provider.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Note: There is a bug with jUnit platform and surefire plugin 2.20.0 so stick with 2.19.1 for now.

Here is the complete project on the KotlinTest website: https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/tree/master/kotlintest-samples/kotlintest-samples-maven